# Can I prevent Safari from using the .download extension or not have Safari register .download as a package

Tags: safari, data-transfer

When Safari downloads a large file, it temporarily creates a .download folder and stores data inside there. This .download folder is actually registered as a package. Confirmed by looking at /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist and seeing download file types as registered packages.

```
$grep '>download<' Info.plist -B4 -A15
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>download</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>download10.icns</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Safari download</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
        <string>BrowserDocument</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
```

The .download registered file does not get treated correctly by an application in use, so the sensitive data is not stored in the sensitive data drive, but redirected to the local drive then needs to be manually moved to the sensitive data drive after it is completed the download and obtained the original file name.

So the question is: could this behavior be turned off so it download to the original filename, or some other type or maybe modify this registration so that the .download extension will not be registered as a package?

Thus allowing the file to land directly on the data drive.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why not tell us you are actually trying to achieve, rather than what you think you might need to do to achieve it? It sounds like you are trying to directly download to a non-default location, which should be no issue if that location is an external drive or mounted Mac share.

Comment: The non default location does not allow Mac packages to be saved there. So when downloading a big logs.tar.gz file, safari downloads logs.tar.gz.download and if it is pointed to the non-default location, the application bumps it out, and Safari then saves the file to the Downloads folder. As soon as all dowloaded, Safari renames the file logs.tar.gz nd then opens it up to logs.tar.  The problem is the desktop may not be on a secure device, so the logs should not be put there. The download should go directly to the non-default location which is a cloud location.

Comment: I won't go into wondering why you consider a cloud location to be more secure than the desktop (which hopefully is stored on an encrypted disk). But the question seems to be rather "how can I securely store data downloaded from a website", with a possible answer being "create an encrypted dmg on the cloud drive and download into that". :-)

Comment: It is not guaranteed to be a any specific desktop when accessing the servers logs. But the cloud drive can be connected from any desk. A dmg on the drive would be overkill and perhaps not accessible by different techs if they need to pickup the case from a windows computer. Also, each case has a separate folder with new logs, so it is tedious to download them. If using windows to download logs, they go right into the share drive with no problem.

Comment: Workaround here. Simply use Firefox and the log file lands on the share drive no problem. But need one more step to unpack.